# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable - python 3.5

Tags: python, data-transform

While doing data transformation, I am getting "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable", I am using python 3.5

This is the code snippet,

```
for idx, val in enumerate(aircrashdf.Destination):
if ',' in val:
    destination = val.split(",")
    original = destination[0].strip()
    aircrashdf.iloc[idx,10] = original
```

This is the output

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/drogon/PycharmProjects/aircrashes.py", line 151, in <module>
    if ',' in val:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Add code and o/p directly instead of images

Comment: You are confusing StackOverflow with Imgur. We care about code, not about pictures. If you have a specific problem, consider studying [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) , provide code respecting [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I am not retyping your pictures in my IDE to help you out, sorry.

Comment: Done, edited the question.

Comment: @Ahsaan-566 check by printing `val`, i think its an integer value .

Comment: It's unlikely that your problem really is in line 151 of that 5-line program.  Please construct a [mcve] and show us the error from that exact program.

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` loop, the `val` value is a type of `integer` and you are trying to search `,` in an `integer`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that type of val variable is int, you can check type of any function and variable by using type() function..it will return the type of variable....you can also compare the type of variable by using following code...
'

```
# if type is same as you provided then it will return true
if isinstance(var_name, data_type):
# your code here
```

'